# Select row with ID, different value in other column SQL Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got this:

**ID  A  B  C  D   ID2**
1    |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1    |    1
1    |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1  |   1
1   |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1   | 2
1   |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1   | 3
2   |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1   | 1
2   |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1   | 2
2   |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1   | 3
3   |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1   |  1
3    |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1   | 1
3   |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1   |  1
3   |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1   |  2
3   |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1   |  2
3   |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1   |  2

What it needs to do is show me always the first record of the ID. If value ID2 changes, that's what also must be shown. So it should look like this:

**ID  A  B  C  D   ID2**
1|    1 |   1    |    1  |   1   |      1
1  |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1  |   2
1  |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1   |  3
2  |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1    | 1
2  |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1     | 2
2 |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1  |    3
3  |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1  |    1
3  |    1 |   1    |    1  |   1   |   2

I have tried it like this but that isn't working good. It doesn't give me the first record of a value ID and I still get double values while ID2 doesn't change.

```
SELECT 
IIf(IsNull(m.bsn),'',CStr(m.bsn)) AS BSN, 
IIf(IsNull(m.uitkering),'',CStr(m.uitkering)) AS Uitkering,
IIf(IsNull(m.ingangsdatum),'',Format(m.ingangsdatum,'dd-mm-yyyy')) AS IngangsdatumUitkering, 
IIf(IsNull(m.eerste_ziektedag),'',Format(m.eerste_ziektedag,'dd-mm-yyyy')) AS EersteZiektedag, 
IIf(IsNull(m.ingangsdatum_w),'',Format(m.ingangsdatum_w,'dd-mm-yyyy')) AS DatumWijziging, 
IIf(IsNull(m.ao_percentage),'',CStr(m.ao_percentage)) AS PercentageUitkering 

FROM (((mutatie_historie AS m LEFT JOIN recht_soorten AS rs ON rs.recht_soort_id = m.recht_soort_id) 
                          LEFT JOIN uitkering_soorten AS us ON us.uitkering_soort_id = m.uitkering_soort_id) 
                          LEFT JOIN ao_klassen AS aok ON aok.ao_klasse_id = m.ao_klasse_id) 
                          LEFT JOIN kenmerk_percentage_uitkering AS kpu ON kpu.kenmerk_code = m.kenmerk_code

WHERE m.ongemax_dagloon > '0' 

AND (m.ao_percentage <> (SELECT TOP 1  m9.ao_percentage FROM mutatie_historie m9 WHERE m.bsn < m9.bsn AND m.ingangsdatum_w < m9.ingangsdatum_w )) 

AND not exists 
(SELECT null FROM mutatie_historie m2 WHERE m2.aanlevering > m.aanlevering     AND m2.ingangsdatum_w <= m.ingangsdatum_w AND m2.bsn = m.bsn AND 
    (SELECT Iif(IsNull(m3.uitkering), '', m3.uitkering) FROM mutatie_historie m3 WHERE m3.bsn = m2.bsn AND m3.aanlevering = m2.aanlevering AND m3.keynummer = 
        (SELECT min(keynummer) FROM mutatie_historie m4 WHERE m4.bsn = m3.bsn AND m4.aanlevering = m3.aanlevering AND m4.uitkering is not null) ) = 
            (SELECT Iif(IsNull(m3.uitkering), '', m3.uitkering) FROM mutatie_historie m3 WHERE m3.bsn = m.bsn AND m3.aanlevering = m.aanlevering AND m3.keynummer = 
                (SELECT min(keynummer) FROM mutatie_historie m4 WHERE m4.bsn = m3.bsn AND m4.aanlevering = m3.aanlevering AND m4.uitkering is not null) ) )

ORDER BY m.bsn,  m.ingangsdatum_w, m.ao_percentage DESC;
```

This is my whole code. All of the parts are necessary, this is the part it is about:

```
 AND (m.ao_percentage <> (SELECT TOP 1  m9.ao_percentage FROM mutatie_historie m9 WHERE m.bsn < m9.bsn AND m.ingangsdatum_w < m9.ingangsdatum_w ))
```

Comment: `select distinct ID, ID2 from tablename`.

Comment: Your query mentions 3 columns while example data has only 2 columns. Show real table structure.

Comment: Real table structure has 6 columns but the check is about column bsn and column ao_percentage, the other columns are just for information.

Comment: ORDER BY is missing in `SELECT TOP 1  m9.ao_percentage FROM mutatie_historie m9 WHERE m.bsn < m9.bsn AND m.ingangsdatum_w < m9.ingangsdatum_w`

Answer (score 2):

You shuold use distinct

```
 select distinct ID, ID2
 from your table
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a basic `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
SELECT ID, ID2
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY ID, ID2
ORDER BY ID, ID2;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you need a table structure like this? Maybe you should rethink your database design first.

Then, what you might do is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, ID2
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: The database exist like this for years, it's not mine. I just need to get some data out of it. There is one database (mutatie_historie) but there is an input which overwrites data. That's what the below part is about, to get all the current data and not all the data for a bsn.

Answer (score 0):

To get `ao_percentage` from the first row of `m9` which exeeds `m.bsn`, `m.ingangsdatum_w`

```
...
(SELECT TOP 1 m9.ao_percentage FROM mutatie_historie m9 WHERE m.bsn < m9.bsn AND m.ingangsdatum_w < m9.ingangsdatum_w ORDER BY m9.bsn, m9.ingangsdatum_w)
...
```